# Find and edit php.ini on centos 6.7

Tags: php, mysql, centos

I try to increase the upload limit for phpmyadmin on centos 6.7.

Please help me to find the path of php.ini and wich line should i edit.

I find some threads on the net about /etc/php.ini but there is on max_upload_size = 128M and in phpmyadmin is allowing only 2.4 M

And i m confused.

any one knows ? thanks.

Comment: You can use [`phpinfo()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.phpinfo.php) to display which .ini file is loaded.

Comment: maybe `find . -name "php.ini"` in console? to find all php.ini's

Answer (score 0):

In `php.ini` you have `upload_max_filesize = ;` also `post_max_size`

**LE:** presuming you have a WHM Panel, you can search for PHP Configuration Editor in the navigation => check the Advanced Mode => find `post_max_size` and set it to a higher value ex. 128M => find `upload_max_filesize` and set it to a higher value ex. 128M ( please mind the caps on M ) => in the nav search for `http`, you should see `HTTP Server (Apache)`. now restart and check in phpmyadmin if the value has changed.

If you don't have a WHM Panel for your server than do what Glorfindel suggested and upload a php file with the `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` content and check for the loaded php.ini file. next edit that file same configuration variables `upload_max_filesize` and `post_max_size`, but i think the one that the phpmyadmin is checking for is the `post_max_size`. after you saved the changes restart apache ( I think `sudo service httpd restart` in terminal ).

Comment: in /etc/php.ini the upload_max_filesize is 128M but in the phpmyadmin on upload is 2.4MB

is the right path?

Comment: after you updated your php.ini did you restart your httpd service(apache)?

Comment: i dont have edite the php ini. was by default 128M but in phpmyadmin was showing 2.4. i think is not the right file.

Comment: i modified my answer, please try it out. if you don't have a whm panel, you will need to run some terminal commands and file editing maybe.